# read .ser file in Java give me an FileNotFoundException and access denied

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I was given an assignment to read a file and play with the data inside the file but I cannot read from the file, is giving me an exception which looks like this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\MariaAle y Omar\Documents\bacon.ser (Access is denied)
```

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
{
    String dataPath = "C:\\Users\\MariaAle y Omar\\Documents\\bacon.ser";
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(dataPath));

}
```

Please I would like to know what is my error, thank you in advavance.

Comment: "Access is denied" that's most likely the issue, no?

Comment: yes, is not letting me read the file.

Comment: so give the user running the java code access to the file..

Comment: How I do that??

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

Comment: Thanks that really help!!!!!!

Comment: so your issue is fixed or this is some irony? (if fixed, please post some answer and accept it)